RedGear Elite-V2 Game Controller on 24.04
I am trying to use RedGear Elite-V2 Game Controller with RetroArch in 24.04. It is a wireless game controller but also connects through a USB cable. I am unable to make it work either wirelessly or through USB cable. Is there any chance I can get it working on Ubuntu 24.04? Thanks.

I was able to use it wirelessly. Not sure which worked, I installed 3 drivers

sudo apt-get install xboxdrv

xpadneo

xpad


https://github.com/atar-axis/xpadneo
https://github.com/paroj/xpad
Please note that it works only as wireless game controller, not working for me as USB game controller. I had Settings > Driver > udev in RetroArch.
